# Carriage returns are prevent sed reading all my files

Tags: bash, text-processing, newlines

I have a long list of folders, inside every folder I have the file "log.dat".
I wanted to read the value of a specific line inside this file. 
I saved the folders names in a file "All.txt", in the parent folder, then I ran this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
in=/a/b/c   #path to the file All.txt  
for i in $(cat $in/all.txt); do
sed -n '/price/p' ${in}/${i}/log.dat

done
```

This code was able to read almost all the files but for some reason, which I can't figure it out!! It was output the following error message:

```
/log.dat: No such file or directory #(then the path to this file)
```

If I run the command `sed -n '/price/p' log.dat` inside the folder that output the error message. I get an answer!

PS:
The content of the file ALL.txt ( which is created by running the command `ls>All.txt` in the parent folder) is as follow:

```
STR-548-021-01
STR-548-021-02
STR-548-022-01
STR-548-022-02
STR-548-023-01
STR-548-023-02
.
.
.
.
.
```

I tried to use the command "awk" instead of "sed" as follow:

```
awk '{ price }' ${in}/${i}/log.dat
```

And I got the same error message.

Can these carriage returns happen in Linux as an output for the command ls>All.txt?

Comment: @don_crissti. Thanks! Kindly, How can I use "xargs" instead? Also, This command worked very well for almost all my files. Why it is unable to read some of them. They all identical

Comment: there are no trailing spaces!

Comment: I got the same error message stating that there is no file or directory

Comment: `find ./ -iname log.dat -print0 | sort -z |  xargs -0 -L 1 sed -n '/price/p' | tee result.dat` xargs use, like that as example

Comment: @ MolbOrg. Thanks!. I got with xargs, the same error message

Comment: try the same, but `find ./ -iname log.dat -type f -readable -print0 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [carriage returns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return#Computers) at the end of `$i`, because there are carriage returns at the end of the lines in `all.txt`. It was probably produced on Windows: Windows uses the two-character sequence CR,LF to mark a line break, whereas Unix (and most of the rest of the world) uses just LF (linefeed, synonym of newline in the Unix world), so Unix sees a line with a CR at the end.

Either convert your file to Unix line endings, or strip off the CR:

```
for i in $(cat $in/all.txt); do
  i=${i%$'\r'}
  sed -n '/price/p' ${in}/${i}/log.dat
done
```

This does nothing if there's no CR at the end of a line. Explanation: `$'\r'` [is a carriage return](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting), and `${i%…}` [is the value of `i` minus the specified suffix](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Note that your script expects blank-separated input, not one file per line, and the input is a list of wildcard patterns, not file names. See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) . This makes no difference if there are no spaces or wildcards in the input.

Comment: Thanks! The file All.txt was created by running the command ls > All.txt in the parent folder .

Comment: @goro I doubt it: that wouldn't insert CR. Are you running under Windows? In what environment?

Comment: No I am a Linux user. But adding   i=${i%$'\r'} to the code worked well

Comment: Gilless. Thanks a lot for this info. You are great! Kindly could you please explain to me what " i=${i%$'\r'} " is standing for?

Comment: @goro `i=${i%foo}` sets `i` to its current value, minus `foo` at the end. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: You are awesome Thanks a lot!! I keep learning from you :)

Comment: You can also use programs `unix2dos` and `dos2unix` for CR inserting and CR removal, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message indicates that sed is getting an argument of /log.dat - neither $i or $in are set to any value. I think you have a blank line in your All.txt file.

> /log.dat: No such file or directory #(then the path to this file)

Comment: You are right. it is something related to the file ALL.txt. But it is also something that I was unable to understand!!! The folders names are sorted bellow each other and no blanck spaces between them. I did back slash for the foloowing line to the folder name that output the error then I pressed enter and every thing went fine. Why ?

Comment: No, if the variables were unset, that would be `//log.dat`. They're set — but the last one ends with a CR which causes the end of the file name to overwrite the beginning of the line.